# Checking a boolean after returning a boolean from a function

Tags: php, class

I am utterly confused: why won't my method of function work?

I have a slight problem, I am not sure where it is coming from though, but I'd like to check first if my IF statements are the cause, yet in java `if(var){ //var is true }` works, yet in PHP, it seems more complex than my understanding of booleans.

I am attempting to check if a boolean is true after getting `return true;` from a function I've used in check.

Some of my code is this.

IF: `if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) === true`
FUNCTION:

```
    public function userValidMC($user){

        // grab data
        $minecraftOutput = file_get_contents('https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=' . $user . '');

        return $minecraftOutput;

    }
```

Am I checking something wrong, or is my code completely wrong (the function)?

Comment: Does the URL in your example _really_ return the PHP value "true" or is it returning the _string_ true?

Comment: You are checking if a string is of type bool and set to true, which strings are not.

Comment: You don't seems to returning `true` from your function.

Comment: Pretty sure file_get_contents returns a string, you might want to find some indication of an invalid user to generate your boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote service returns a string, either `'true'` or `'false'`, so the return value should be:

```
return trim($minecraftOutput) === 'true';
```

Comment: Thought that file_get_contents will fail because of 404 error. Let us see what the OP says

Comment: @hek2mgl Nope, it returns `(string)false` apparently, so it was reasonable to assume it would be `(string)true` on success :)

Comment: Yes, I've tested for myself now. Couldn't really believe this! ;). Nice catch! +1

Answer (score 3):

The method will actually return a string. (have tested with [this](https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=hek2mgl) url) Change the `if` to:

```
if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) !== 'false'
```

This is because if the user exists, the method will return the page content and not a boolean `true`. But you are testing for `=== true`. But if the user doesn't exists the method will return false as `file_get_contents()` fails. So you should check for that.

Another way - which I would prefer - is to change the method to:

```
public function userValidMC($user){
    // grab data
    // the page will return the string 'false' if the user does not exist
    $minecraftOutput = file_get_contents('https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=' . $user . '');
    return $minecraftOutput !== 'false';
}
```

... and the (original) `if` statement:

```
if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) === true
```

Comment: +1: Though I shutter when I see this, I understand the work around -`file_get_contents` will consistently return a `bool` value of `false` on a failure but nothing else is consistent!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Yes if the url will return a 404, `file_get_contents()` will return `bool(false)`

Comment: Thank you, this has seemed to worked along with Jack's answer. Shame I can't mark two answers as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the results of file_get_contents.
That contains the contents of the file, not a boolean value.
I would suggest that you check to see if the file exists and then see if there is a length to the content.

Comment: On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

Comment: So it does.  Thanks for that note.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents will return either the contents of the file, or false.

Using triple = means compare value and type, so you are saying if that functions returns a boolean of TRUE, which it won't,

Answer (score 0):

The if you posted checks wether the function "userValidMC" has returned true, note that you are using ===, so you are checking for the actual "true" boolean value, and not just wether the value evaluates to true (using ==).

```
if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) === true)
```

However, that function returns the result of file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

This function returns the contents of the file or false on failure, so it should never return true.

You can check the result this way:

```
if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'file_get_contents' returns a string on success and false on failure.

If you're simply testing that you get a valid response from the call then:

```
return $minecraftOutput !== false;
```

Will return a boolean value.

Or if you're checking for a specific value in the response then:

```
return $minecraftOutput === "expectedValue";
```

If you wanted to be less strict then:

```
if($user->userValidMC($_POST['username']) == true)
```

Will pass (most) strings with a length larger than 0, but returning a strict boolean value out of your function is safer.

See: [PHP type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)